# Too many script statements

Tags: apex-code

If I want to populate an array with a large number of primative type values using a loop. How can I overcome the Too many code statements limit?

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[]{};
for(Integer i=0; i<500000; i++) {
     arr.add(i);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm

It shows some limits on amount of scripts in the code I think you are working in.

Tell me if it works!

Comment: I'm familiar with the limits shown in the docs.  So, the total number of executed code statements cannot exceed 200,000.  Is there another way to populate a list with 500,000 values and not hit the code statement limit?

Comment: Sorry I have not been able to answer this whole time... Has the problem been resolved by now...?